# Understanding the max function operation on Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, max

I am trying to understand the operation on max function on Python dictionary. Following is the code I am using:

```
tall_buildings = { 
    "Empire State": 381, "Sears Tower": 442,
    "Burj Khalifa": 828, "Taipei 101": 509 
}


# 1. find the height of the tallest building
print("Height of the tallest building: ", max(tall_buildings.values()))


# 2. find the name, height pair that is tallest
print(max(tall_buildings.items(), key=lambda b: b[1]))


# 3. find the tallest building
print(max(tall_buildings, key=tall_buildings.get))
```

All the above print statements gives the correct results as indicated in the comments in the code.

I understood how `#1` and `#2` works.

> 1: `tall_buildings.values()` gives a stream of heights and `max` function returns the max of the heights.
>
> 2: `tall_buildings.items()` gives a stream of (name, height) pairs and max function returns the pair based on the `key=pair's height.`

However, I have difficulty in understanding how `# 3` works. How does `key=tall_buildings.get` serve as the key for finding the tallest building ?

I have taken the code from Ned's Pycon Talk: https://youtu.be/EnSu9hHGq5o?t=12m42s

Comment: dict.get method takes a key and returns the associated value. So, the max function is going to run through all the entries in the dictionary and give the pair associated with the maximum height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max()` function *iterates* over its first argument, applies the key function to each item and selects the item with the maximum key.

Iterating over a dictionary is the same as iterating over its keys.  When executing

```
max(tall_buildings, key=tall_buildings.get)
```

we will first iterate over all keys in `tall_buildings`.  For each key `k` the key function `tall_buildings.get(k)` will be evaluated, which returns the height of the building denoted by `k`.  Then the `k` with the maximum height will be selected and returned.

Answer (score 2):

The way that #3 works is that the method provided as the `key` will simply lookup the value from the `tall_buildings` dictionary. So for each `key` being iterated over, the corresponding `value` will be provided by `get`.

The `get` method is synonymous with the `[]` operator

```
>>> tall_buildings['Sears Tower']
442
>>> tall_buildings.get('Sears Tower')
442
```

The reason #3 is looping over the keys in the first place, is that by default iterating over a `dict` will loop over *only the keys*

```
for i in tall_buildings:
    print(i)

Taipei 101
Empire State
Burj Khalifa
Sears Tower
```

You can also loop over the keys explicitly

```
for i in tall_buildings.keys():
    print(i)

Taipei 101
Empire State
Burj Khalifa
Sears Tower
```

Similarly you can loop over `.values()` which are only the values in the dictionary, or `.items()` which loops over tuples of `(key,value)` pairs.

Comment: but we're not giving the key there, are we?

Comment: @harshil9968 Iterating over a dictionary is the same as iterating over its keys.

Comment: Is the parameter that is passed each time to tall_buildings.get, the keys of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of max requires a definition of *ordering* of items.

So here you are providing `key` parameter just as you would do to [sort](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/): a function to apply to each element of the dictionary in order to map the `(key, val)` pairs to values which have in-built ordering definition (e.g. numbers, strings). So you will find the max of the *mapped* values and the result will be the corresponding element in the original dictionary.